# Should I take view translation into account when overriding onDraw?

Tags: android, drawing, transformation, android-canvas

Should I take view translation into account when overriding `onDraw()`? Or it is already applied to canvas translation?

I.e. should I execute

```
canvas.translate(getTranslationX(), getTranslationY());
```

in first line of `onDraw()`?

Do all transformations applied to canvas in `onDraw()` call persist in subsequent calls? I.e. should I suppose `canvas` is each time untransformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to do this. A View's translation is applied before onDraw is called.

As HardCoder points out, state changes that you make to the Canvas passed to onDraw will not persist to the next call to onDraw.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the canvas is not persistant therefore you should execute the translate. However you can save the canvas and restore it:

http://maohao.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/canvas-save-canvas-restore/

[Android View.onDraw() always has a clean Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423327/android-view-ondraw-always-has-a-clean-canvas)

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/moving-views-in-android-part-1/