# Using view's drawingCache on VIew.onDraw() for smooth scrolling

Tags: android, view, scroll

I would like to implement a custom View with smooth scrolling feature. I have read [Android View.onDraw() always has a clean Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423327/android-view-ondraw-always-has-a-clean-canvas). By building an off-screen bitmap, it even take some more time to draw the off-screen bitmap. Therefore, I have think of using the view drawing cache.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    long start = System.nanoTime(); 
    if(redrawAll){
        drawFullScreen(canvas);
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cachedBitmap = SampleView4.this.getDrawingCache();
            }                   
        });
    }
    else{
        if(cachedBitmap != null && !cachedBitmap.isRecycled()){
            canvas.drawBitmap(cachedBitmap ,scrollByX, scrollByY, p);
            drawPartOfScreen(canvas, scrollByX, scrollByY);
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cachedBitmap = SampleView4.this.getDrawingCache();
            }                   
        });
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "drawTiles take: "+(System.nanoTime() - start) + " ns");     

}
```

It probably work but have strange behaviour. Sometime, the cached `Bitmap` do no change after `onDraw()` and thus look very weird.

And, the main problem is the performance do not have not much different with just call `drawFullScreen(canvas);` each time the view scrolls.

Am I on the right track? I have develop on Android 4 so I turn on the hardware acceleration. But the docs say the view has cached in hardware-texture. Do I really need drawing cache in hardware acceleration environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't rely on drawing cache when hardware acceleration is ON. According the doc about View.setDrawingCacheEnabled() :

"Enabling the drawing cache is similar to setting a layer when hardware acceleration is turned off. When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag. If you want to use a Bitmap for the view, even when hardware acceleration is enabled, see setLayerType(int, android.graphics.Paint) for information on how to enable software and hardware layers."