# How to draw to Canvas from SurfaceView?

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I'm trying to do simple painter. The problem that it looks like Android has three independent Canvas and give me it for drawing sequentially.

I made UI with `SurfaceView`, took Holder from it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    holder = sv.getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(callback);
}
```

Then took Surface.

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surface = holder.getSurface();
}
```

And by events from `OnTouchListener()` draw dots and lines.

```
private void paintStartDot(float x, float y) {
    Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);

    canvas.drawPoint(x, y, drawPaint);
    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}

private void paintEndDot(float x, float y) {
    Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);

    canvas.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y, drawPaint);

    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}
```

The screencast:

https://youtu.be/NNDnzrtMLZI

What is wrong?

Full source is available here: 
https://github.com/tseglevskiy/canvasdemo1/blob/error/app/src/main/java/ru/jollydroid/canvasdemo1/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Canvas` that `Surface.lockCanvas` gives you is *not persistent*. The moment you call `unlockCanvasAndPost`, the contents of the surface buffer are pushed out to the screen. Every time you call `lockCanvas` you need to redraw the picture from scratch.

If you want to update the canvas incrementally, you should keep an "off-screen" [canvas backed by a `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)) that you update in response to user actions. Then paint the bitmap to the `Surface` canvas.

```
private void paintStartDot(float x, float y) {
    if (mBitmap == null) return;  // not ready yet
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    canvas.drawPoint(x, y, drawPaint);

    // draw the bitmap to surface 
    canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // good place to create the Bitmap
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config. ARGB_8888);
    // also here we need to transform the old bitmap to new one
}
```

I'm not sure if you really need a `SurfaceView`. You could just extend the `View` and override its `View.onDraw` method. In that case, call `view.invalidate()` to indicate it needs to be redrawn.

See also: [Android View.onDraw() always has a clean Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423327/android-view-ondraw-always-has-a-clean-canvas)

Comment: More information about custom views: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html